# Showing html in Javascript and loop control

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

I'm having an issue with this code.  I am trying to build a calendar.  The HTML file is just a bunch of divs with date, month, and year selectors.  When I click on the year or day (or select the month when decide to add the onClick attribute), a buildCalendar() function is called in the Javascript.  The problem is that I am having some repeated values for Sunday and Saturday so that the days don't quite line up right. Additionally, notice that a value will sometimes be placed to the right of the Saturday column (outside of the calendar altogether) the I've been stuck the last couple of days trying to figure it out and its getting on my nerves!

Another problem is that when I click on the date to build the calendar, the calendar builds but the date(and year and month) selectors disappear.  I would like for them to not disappear, so that I can click a different year or month or day and have the calendar change dynamically.

Here is the CSS, HTML, and Javascript Codes.  I would make a fiddle but it doesnt allow document.write() and I am using that method in order to build the calendar.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = ".CSS/calendar.css">  
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "./Calendar/calendar.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "task.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "setDate();">
    <div id = "wrapper">
    <div id="topleft">
        <p><h2><script type="text/javascript"> var someMonth = document.getElementById("myMonth");  </script></h2>

            <label for="myDay">Day:   </label><input type="number" id="myDay" min="1" max="31" onclick="buildCalendar();"/>
            <label for="myMonth">Month:   </label><select id="myMonth" size="1" onClick = "buildCalendar";>
            <option value="0">January</option>
            <option value="1">February</option>
            <option value="2">March</option>
            <option value="3">April</option>
            <option value="4">May</option>
            <option value="5">June</option>
            <option value="6">July</option>
            <option value="7">August</option>
            <option value="8">September</option>
            <option value="9">October</option>
            <option value="10">November</option>
            <option value="11">December</option>
            </select>
            <label for="myYear">Year:   </label><input type="number" id="myYear" min="1900" onClick = "buildCalendar();" />


    </div>
    <div id = "topRight"> Shows the form to add task </div>
    <div id = "bottomRight"> Show list of tasks </div>
    <div id = "bottomLeft" > Shows calendar </div>
    <div id = "left">  Left Div   </div>
    <div id = "right"> Right Div </div>
    </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code is just used for positioning and coloring primarily, but I figure I don't need to worry about that until the calendar builds successfully and I can see the date selectors.

```
body{
background-color:black;
}
#wrapper {
size:950px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:green;
border-color:black;
}
#left {
size:50%
float:left;
background-color:yellow;
}
#right{
size:50%;
float:right;
background-color:red;
}
#bottomLeft{
background-color:red;
}
#topLeft{
float:left;
position:absolute;
z-index:100;
}
```

The real issue is probably somewhere in the Javascript.  The variables are created in order to determine the first date of the month, the last date, the year, etc.  The FOR statement iterates through the month starting with the first day and ending with the last day and adds a  for each day, closing the row on 
Saturday (at least that is what it is supposed to do).  Also, I can't figure out why the date selectors from the HTML are not showing up.  Here is the Javascript.

```
function setDate(){
   var today = new Date();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var day = today.getDate();
    document.getElementById("myDay").value = day;
    document.getElementById("myMonth").value = month;
    document.getElementById("myYear").value = year;
}
function buildCalendar(){
var firstDate = new Date(document.getElementById("myYear").value, document.getElementById("myMonth").value, 1);
var weekDay = firstDate.getDay();
var theDate = firstDate.getDate();
var theMonth = firstDate.getMonth();
var theYear = firstDate.getFullYear();
var newDay = new Date(theYear, theMonth + 1, 1);
var lastDate = new Date(newDay - 1);
var lastDay = lastDate.getDate();
var aMonth = document.getElementById("myMonth").selectedIndex.text;
document.write("<table class='caltable' border='1'><tr><th>");
document.write("<tr><th>Sunday</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th>");
document.write("</th></tr>");
var col = 0;
for (var i = 1-weekDay;i<=lastDay;i++)
    {
        if(col == 0 && weekDay != 6)
        {
        document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
        col++;
        }
        //prevents the day from sliding to the right if the first of the month is a Saturday
        if(col == 0 && weekDay == 6)
        {
        document.write("<tr><td>" + i + "</td></tr>" );
        col++;
        }
        if (col > 6)
        {
        document.write("<td>" + i + "</td></tr>");
        col = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
        document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
        }
                col++;
    }
    document.write("</table>");
    }
/*function getMonthName()
{
var e = document.getElementById("myMonth").selectedIndex.value;
alert(e);
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` shouldn't be used after the page is loaded. If you use it after, it will overwrite the document. Instead add a table tag with id=table at the beggining and use this in javascript,

```
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;
```

This code will solve the dynamic loading problem.. (style is not added)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = ".CSS/calendar.css">  
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "./Calendar/calendar.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "task.js"></script>
    <script>
    function setDate(){
         var today = new Date();
        var year = today.getFullYear();
        var month = today.getMonth();
        var day = today.getDate();
        document.getElementById("myDay").value = day;
        document.getElementById("myMonth").value = month;
        document.getElementById("myYear").value = year;
    }
    function buildCalendar(){
            var firstDate = new Date(document.getElementById("myYear").value, document.getElementById("myMonth").value, 1);
            var weekDay = firstDate.getDay();
            var theDate = firstDate.getDate();
            var theMonth = firstDate.getMonth();
            var theYear = firstDate.getFullYear();
            var newDay = new Date(theYear, theMonth + 1, 1);
            var lastDate = new Date(newDay - 1);
            var lastDay = lastDate.getDate();
            vaMonth = document.getElementById("myMonth").selectedIndex.text;
            var html = "<table class='caltable' border='1'><tr><th>";
            html += "<tr><th>Sunday</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th>";
            html += "</th></tr>";
            var col = 0;
            for (var i = 1-weekDay;i<=lastDay;i++)
                {
                    if(col == 0 && weekDay != 6)
                    {
                    html += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
                    col++;
                    }
                    //prevents the day from sliding to the right if the first of the month is a Saturday
                    if(col == 0 && weekDay == 6)
                    {
                    html += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td></tr>";
                    col++;
                    }
                    if (col > 6)
                    {
                    html += "<td>" + i + "</td></tr>";
                    col = 0;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    html += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
                    }
                    col++;
                }
                html += "</table>";

            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;
    }
    /*function getMonthName()
    {
    var e = document.getElementById("myMonth").selectedIndex.value;
    alert(e);
    }*/
    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "setDate();">
<div id = "wrapper">
<div id="topleft">
    <p><h2><script type="text/javascript"> var someMonth = document.getElementById("myMonth");  </script></h2>

        <label for="myDay">Day:   </label><input type="number" id="myDay" min="1" max="31" onclick="buildCalendar();"/>
        <label for="myMonth">Month:   </label><select id="myMonth" size="1" onClick = "buildCalendar";>
        <option value="0">January</option>
        <option value="1">February</option>
        <option value="2">March</option>
        <option value="3">April</option>
        <option value="4">May</option>
        <option value="5">June</option>
        <option value="6">July</option>
        <option value="7">August</option>
        <option value="8">September</option>
        <option value="9">October</option>
        <option value="10">November</option>
        <option value="11">December</option>
        </select>
        <label for="myYear">Year:   </label><input type="number" id="myYear" min="1900" onClick = "buildCalendar();" />


</div>
<div id = "topRight"> Shows the form to add task </div>
<div id = "bottomRight"> Show list of tasks </div>
<div id = "bottomLeft" > Shows calendar </div>
<div id = "left">  Left Div   </div>
<div id = "right"> Right Div </div>
</div>
<div id="table"></div>          
</body>
</html>
```